# C++ - why can't the compiler deduce the types for the function template containing constructor parameters?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-templates

I want to use `std::aligned_storage_t` to decouple allocation and construction, so I write two little helpers to help me do this

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T>
using Uninitialized = std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto get_initialized(Uninitialized<T>& block, Args... args) -> T&
    requires(
        // If we allow type with default constructor, then it would be ambiguous
        // if the caller wants initialization or simply getting reference.
        !std::is_default_constructible_v<T> &&
        (sizeof...(Args) == 0 || std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>)
    )
{
    T* p = (T*) &block;
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) > 0)
        new (p) T{args...};
    return *p;
}
```

And I tested it with

```
class Obj {
public:
    Obj() = delete;
    Obj(const char* s) noexcept : m_str(s) {}

    void print() noexcept {
        std::cout << m_str << std::endl;
    }
private:
    const char* m_str = nullptr;
};

int main() {
    Uninitialized<Obj> obj{};
    const char* s = "Test";
    Obj& o = get_initialized(obj, s);
    o.print();
}
```

And it failed. I've tried clang, gcc and msvc, and they all complained about "no matching function call". Complaint from clang

```
<source>:37:14: error: no matching function for call to 'get_initialized'
    Obj& o = get_initialized(obj, s);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Of course, simply add `<Obj>` the code would work fine. But I just want to save some typing here. I found output from gcc providing some insight here

```
<source>:37:29: error: no matching function for call to 'get_initialized(Uninitialized<Obj>&, const char*&)'
   37 |     Obj& o = get_initialized(obj, s);
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

So I guess the problem relates to the type of the parameters of constructor, and I'm also quite curious here why would the type of `s` would be deduced to `char*&` while it's just a 8 byte data and can be copied without extra cost. So is there a way to enforce the parameter to be copied, just like `std::ref` or `std::cref`?

Comment: I don't get why there's an issue with permitting the default constructor here? What exactly is wrong with `template<class T, class...Args> requires std::constructible_from<T, Args> T& get_initialized(Uninitialized<T>& block, Args&& ... args) { return *(new (&block)T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); }` ??? Btw: note that you're not returning a reference, so instead of getting a reference to the newly constructed object, you get a copy that is constructed from that object...

Comment: Well I just want to use this function to do two things at the same time. The version with construction parameters is initialization, and the version without them is simply type conversion. And type with default constructor would break the promise here, since the function can't tell what the caller wants to do. In fact there's no need to wrap around a class with default constructor, since it just constructs.

Comment: Side note: `std::aligned_storage` is obsolete according to C++23, and will be removed in future std revisions. Consider using `union` types instead; the can be lazily constructed from C++20 on.

Comment: Having a function named `get_initialized()` that has an option to not actually initialize an object makes no sense. I would move the "get reference without initialization" logic into a separate function. In which case, your helpers become pretty redundant since the caller can simply type-cast or `new` directly as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Uninitialized<T>` is an alias...

So your template is actually

using Uninitialized = ;

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto get_initialized(std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>& block, Args... args) -> T&
```

`T` is not deducible here (any class with same `sizeof`/`alignof` would be valid).

See [Deduction_from_a_type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_type) for more info

Comment: So if I am not guessing wrong, when the compiler deduces the type, the information about T in sizeof(T) and alignof(T) is already erased, and all it can see is the two size_t? Is there any spec describing what's happening here

Comment: See added [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_type).

Answer (score 2):

You can't deduce against an alias template like this. There are several types `T` for which `Uninitialized<T>` would be the same type as `Uninitialized<Obj>`, namely at least all `T` such that `sizeof(T) == sizeof(Obj)` and `alignof(T) == alignof(Obj)`. Which `T` should the compiler deduce for your call?